# FindClusters for 3D Pancake/Platelet Shapes

Tags: graphics3d, cluster-analysis

I'm looking to properly cluster a dataset of roughly 3 million data points in 3-space. The shapes form closely spaced "clusters" that resemble pancakes.

Here is a downsampled dataset:

```
data = Import["https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28603777/data.wdx"];
```

I have tried the standard distance methods (Canberra, Euclidean, Manhattan and BrayCurtis), yet each leaves some points from one cluster improperly sorted into another.

```
out = FindClusters[data, 6];
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O11qF.png]

The navy platelet "leaks" into the gold platelet due to the fact that the distance methods are isotropic. Also the gold platelet "leaks" into the red platelet.

Is there a different way to cluster such that the distance method can be optimized in this way, or is there a fast way to cluster these platelets that does not rely on this function.

Comment: Not sure if I properly understand your question, but adding `Method -> "Agglomerate"` to the `FindClusters` function seems to do the trick - not sure if that helps for the whole set of data...

Comment: @PinguinDirk Could make that an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the data you provide, it seems that hierarchical clustering (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) here) with type "agglomerate" (bottom up) solves your problem, i.e.:

```
out = FindClusters[data, 6, Method -> "Agglomerate"];
ListPointPlot3D[out]
```

and get:

[image]

Based on how your full dataset looks like (e.g. if you know how many clusters there are etc.), you might need to adapt the code a bit (possibly also with distance function or matrix) - but for the sample you are providing, it seems to work nicely. Also, performance **could** be an issue, as noted in the wiki article.